# UITextView Scroll View showing directly second line

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` which has 290 height fix. So whenever the text exceeds the height, Then the scrolling gets enabled but in my case i don't understand why the scrolling is showing the 2nd line text.[image]

Comment: share some code.

Comment: Please remove margin and try

Comment: Hi @AjharulIslam There is nothing much in the code. Just Adding string to the text.

Comment: it seems there is a view or something in front of scroll view. remove that view or change the scroll view frame . hopefully it will works .

Comment: Yeah There is label, But that isnt blocking it, The problem here what i am facing is that the scroll view in the uitextview shows second ling.

Comment: Hi @ZiyadGodil Which margin are you talking about?

Comment: Please look at my below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code

**Objective C:**

```
[self.textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];
```

**Swift:**

```
self.textView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))
```

**Swift 2 (Alternate Solution)**

Add this overridden method to your ViewController

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    textView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: false)
}
```

**Swift 3 (syntax edit)**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
    }
```

Comment: myTextView.contentOffset.y = 0

Comment: self->_textView.text = @"Text";
[self->_textView setEditable:NO];
[self->_textView setSelectable:NO];
[self->_textView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

Comment: override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // It works, but with an animation effection.
    self.textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
}

Comment: Ok good, Please upvote my answer and comments so other can also benefit from this ;)